# Replace NA values with corresponding non NA values in side column

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a `data.table` named temp:

```
PID PID_Gen 
a   NA   
c   c1
b   NA
d   d1
```

The following evaluates if `PID_Gen` is `NULL` and in that case assigns the value of `PID`.

```
temp$result <- future_sapply(temp$PID_Gen, 
                             FUN = function(x) if(is.na(x)) {temp$PID})
```

The problem is that it overflows the memory.

Are there any alternatives I can use?

Comment: Does this work: `temp$result <- ifelse(is.na(temp$PID_Gen), as.character(temp$PID), as.character(temp$PID_Gen))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your desired result?

```r
df <- read.table(text = "PID PID_Gen 
a   NA   
c   c1
b   NA
d   d1", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$PID_Gen[is.na(df$PID_Gen)] <- df$PID[is.na(df$PID_Gen)]

print(df)
#>   PID PID_Gen
#> 1   a       a
#> 2   c      c1
#> 3   b       b
#> 4   d      d1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach:

```
temp <- read.table(text = "PID PID_Gen 
                   a   NA   
                   c   c1
                   b   NA
                   d   d1", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
temp$result <- ifelse(is.na(temp$PID_Gen), temp$PID, temp$PID_Gen)
```